# Workbox cache group is not correct

Tags: caching, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm using workbox-webpack-plugin v5 (the latest) with InjectManifest plugin. The following is my service worker source file:

```js
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from 'workbox-cacheable-response';
import { clientsClaim, setCacheNameDetails, skipWaiting } from 'workbox-core';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';
import {
  cleanupOutdatedCaches,
  createHandlerBoundToURL,
  precacheAndRoute,
} from 'workbox-precaching';
import { NavigationRoute, registerRoute, setCatchHandler } from 'workbox-routing';
import { CacheFirst, NetworkOnly, StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies';

setCacheNameDetails({
  precache: 'install-time',
  prefix: 'app-precache',
  runtime: 'run-time',
  suffix: 'v1',
});

cleanupOutdatedCaches();

clientsClaim();

skipWaiting();

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

precacheAndRoute([{ url: '/app-shell.html', revision: 'html-cache-1' }], {
  cleanUrls: false,
});

const handler = createHandlerBoundToURL('/app-shell.html');

const navigationRoute = new NavigationRoute(handler);
registerRoute(navigationRoute);


registerRoute(
  /.*\.css/,
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'css-cache-v1',
  })
);


registerRoute(
  /^https:\/\/fonts\.(?:googleapis|gstatic)\.com/,
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'google-fonts-cache-v1',
    plugins: [
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({
        statuses: [0, 200],
      }),
      new ExpirationPlugin({
        maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
        maxEntries: 30,
      }),
    ],
  })
);


registerRoute(
  /.*\.js/,
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'js-cache-v1',
  })
);


setCatchHandler(new NetworkOnly());
```

I have the following questions/problems:

- Cache group is not correct. Everything except google fonts is under `workbox-precache-v2` or `app-precache-install-time-v1` cache group, not individual cache groups such as `css-cache-v1`, `js-cache-v1`. However, 1 in 20 times, it shows correct cache group, and I just can't figure out why.
- Google font shows from memory cache. Is it correct? It works fine in offline, but what will happen if the user closes the browser/machine and comes back in offline mode?
- Is '/app-shell.html' usage correct? It's an express backend app with * as the wild card for all routes, and React Router handles the routing. Functionally, it's working fine offline. I don't have any app-shell.html page.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> Cache group is not correct. Everything except google fonts is under `workbox-precache-v2` or `app-precache-install-time-v1` cache group, not individual cache groups such as `css-cache-v1`, `js-cache-v1`. However, 1 in 20 times, it shows correct cache group, and I just can't figure out why.

It depends on what's in your precache manifest (i.e. what `self.__WB_MANIFEST` gets replaced with during your webpack build).

For example, let's say you have a file generated by webpack called `bundle.js`, and that file ends up in your precache manifest.  Based on your service worker code, that file will end up in a cached called `app-precache-install-time-v1`—even though it also matches your runtime route with the cache `js-cache-v1`.

The reason is because your precache route is registered before you runtime route, so your precaching logic will handle that request rather than your runtime caching logic.

> Google font shows from memory cache. Is it correct? It works fine in offline, but what will happen if the user closes the browser/machine and comes back in offline mode?

I believe this means the request is not being handled by the service worker, but you can check the workbox logs in the developer console to verify (and see why not).

Alternatively, you could update your code to use a custom handler that just logs whether it's running like so:

```js
registerRoute(
  /^https:\/\/fonts\.(?:googleapis|gstatic)\.com/,
  ({request}) => {
    // Log to make sure this function is being called...
    console.log(request.url);
    return fetch(request);
  }
);
```

> Is '/app-shell.html' usage correct? It's an express backend app with * as the wild card for all routes, and React Router handles the routing. Functionally, it's working fine offline. I don't have any app-shell.html page.

Does your express route respond with a file called `app-shell.html`? If so, then you'd probably want your precache revision to be a hash of the file itself (rather than `revision: 'html-cache-1'`). What you have right now should work, but the risk is you'll change the contents of `app-shell.html`, deploy a new version of your app, but your users will still see the old version because you forgot up update `revision: 'html-cache-1'`. In general it's best to use revisions generated as part of your build step.

Comment: Hi @Philip, thanks for the reply. I have some follow up question. Unfortunately, stackoverflow didn't allow enough characters (maybe, it's just a limitation on new users like me), so I posted it on GitHub.

Could you take a look at it whenever you get a chance? Thanks.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2356#issuecomment-585931982